# Interpretation of scikit-learn one class svm scores

Tags: scikit-learn, svm, anomaly-detection

How can I interpret the scores generated by the function `score_samples(X)` from a scikit-learn `OneClassSVM` model? Is there a way to tell when one sample is "more anomalous" than other? The `predict()` and `decision_function()` functions have sign information, yet the `score_samples` function does not have this.

````py
from sklearn.svm import OneClassSVM

X = [[0], [0.44], [0.45], [0.46], [1]]
clf = OneClassSVM(gamma='auto').fit(X)

clf.predict(X)
# array([-1,  1,  1,  1, -1])

clf.score_samples(X)
# array([1.7798..., 2.0547..., 2.0556..., 2.0561..., 1.7332...])
```
````

Answer (score 1):

The sample_scores values, along with a cutoff threshold value, are used to determine whether a value is an outlier or not. You should be careful if you try to compare these sample_score values to see which values may be more anomalous than others. If you are looking to eliminate outliers solely to eliminate them from your data-set, using this value alone on a outlier would not be reason enough to eliminate it.

Comment: Are these values used for the end outlier/not-outlier results that the `predict` method outputs? if so, how are these used?

Comment: Yes to your first question. If the sample_score is outside the cutoff threshold, they will be flagged as an outlier.

Comment: Thanks for the response. In that case, how does the algorithm determines the cutoff threshold automatically?

Comment: The algorithm is computing a decision boundary with minimal volume. Not sure of the exact mathematics used to determine this. If you want to change the threshold, you could look at the sample_scores values and create your own prediction based on a < or > threshold value of your own. Or you can look at this website for some ideas on how to add this threshold to the algorithm. https://pyod.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pyod/models/ocsvm.html

Comment: Do you know if I can use these score values for calculating the rocauc score? This should be a good indicator if high values are corresponding to anomalies without the need for calculating a threshold?